# Problema em consumir JSON com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

Estou tentando executar um teste para obter os dados de um arquivo JSON mas não estou conseguindo.

> app.component.html

```
</div><div ng-app="appCursos" ng-controller="meusCursos">
  <ul>
     <p> {{ cursos.id }}</p> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

> json

```
{"id":7006,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

> app.curso.js

```
angular.module("appCursos").controller("meusCursos", function ($scope, $http) {
  var cursos = [];

  var baseUrl = 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting';

  $http.get(baseUrl).then(function (response) {
    $scope.cursos = response.data;

  })
});
```

[image: aparece este erro]

Comment: *AngularJS* ou *Angular 5*?

Comment: E seu model, tem como mostrar?

Comment: **Paula**, recomendo você a fazer o [**Tour**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**. Sua pergunta diz que está com problemas em consumir *JSON* em *Angular 5*, mas seu código é *AngularJS*. Você pode [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/289547/edit) sua pergunta e esclarecer melhor qual das versões está utilizando, você pode também acessar o tópico [**Como fazer uma boa pergunta?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pelo o que o erro mostra, não existe a coluna `id` do objeto cursos, verifique o json retornado com um console.log($scope.cursos), adicione esse json à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui replicar a mensagem de erro que você obteve com teu código e sim um erro de *injecting*. Quando corrigi o problema, consegui ler o JSON:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="appCursos">
        <div ng-controller="meusCursosController as meusCursos">
            <ul>        
                <p>{{ cursos.id }}</p>
                <p>{{ cursos.content }}</p>
            </ul>       
        </div>  
        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.8/angular.min.js"></script> <script>
angular.module('appCursos', [])
        .controller("meusCursosController", ['$http', '$scope', function($http,$scope) {

            var baseUrl='http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting';

            $http.get(baseUrl).then(function(result) {
                $scope.cursos = result.data;
            });

        }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

É necessário colocar tanto **$http** quando **$scope** dentro dentro do controle.

Outra alternativa seria não usar **$scope** e trabalhar com o *this* para acessar/criar atributos do/no próprio controle:

```
var baseUrl = #...;
meusCursos = this;
meusCursos.cursos = [];
# ...
    meusCursos = result.data;
# ...
```

E daí acessá-los no HTML como `meusCursos.cursos.id` e `meusCursos.cursos.content`.

Comment: segui os passos coloquei $http e o $scope e continuo obtendo o mesmo erro

Comment: Teste este meu exemplo no Firefox mas no Chromium ele reclamou de algumas coisas, corrigi o problema (era fora do programa) e ele passou a funcionar. Meu exemplo está em AngularJS 1.6.8 e creio que você esteja usando o Angular 2, correto?

Comment: estou usando a versão 1.6.9

Comment: Salvando o código que colei na resposta em um arquivo HTML e o abrindo no navegador (Chrome, Firefox etc), dá o mesmo erro?

Comment: sim. Tentei exemplos sem ler arquivos e está acontecendo a mesma coisa. Acho que é algum problema com o angular, parece que as expressões e diretivas não estão sendo reconhecidas

Comment: eu segui esse exemplo (http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) criando o projeto com "ng new my-app". Modifiquei o arquivo index.html de acordo com a sua resposta. Os erros são os mesmos.

Comment: Peguei o exemplo do pessoal do Spring e ele funcionando quando executado diretamente pelo navegador, isto é, `firefox hello.html` tanto com as versões 1.4.3 (original do exemplo) como 1.6.8 (última versão da série 1.x). Mas você disse que está usando "ng new ...", isso não é do Angular 2?